# Change background colour of selected Items hides the ListView checkboxes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, checkbox, graphics

I found the following code which does a good job of modifying the background colour of selected items. However, the CheckBox for that line disappears.
Originally the CheckBoxes were not in their own columns so I was shifting everything 20 to the right. However, that didn't fix the issue.
I've now created a column or the CheckBoxes, the selected line is highlighted but you still cannot see the CheckBoxes either under the colored bar, or, if shifted right, left of the bar.
Clicking where the CheckBox should be still puts a tick in but you only see the box when you move off the line.

Any ideas about getting the CheckBox back, I've looked through `DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs` and cannot see anything that will do it.

```
Private Sub lsvFileList2_DrawSubItem(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs) Handles lsvFileList2.DrawSubItem
    Dim NewBounds As Rectangle
    If e.Item.Selected = True Then
        NewBounds = e.Bounds
        NewBounds.X = e.Bounds.X + 20
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.Purple), NewBounds)
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Text, New Font(Me.Font, Nothing), New Point(e.Bounds.Left + 3, e.Bounds.Top + 2), Color.AntiqueWhite)
    Else
        e.DrawDefault = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Modified code after suggestions from Jimi:

```
Private Sub lsvFileList1_DrawSubItem(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs) Handles lsvFileList1.DrawSubItem
    Dim NewBounds As Rectangle
    Dim PurpleBrush As SolidBrush
    Dim glyphSize = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(e.Graphics, VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal)
    Dim p = New Point(e.Bounds.Location.X + 4, e.Bounds.Y + CInt((e.Bounds.Height - glyphSize.Height) / 2))

    Using PurpleBrush
        PurpleBrush = New SolidBrush(Color.Purple)
    End Using
    If e.Item.Selected = True Then
        NewBounds = e.Bounds
        NewBounds.X = e.Bounds.X + 20
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(PurpleBrush, NewBounds)
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Text, New Font(Me.Font, Nothing), p, Color.AntiqueWhite, Color.Purple)
        If e.Bounds.Left = 0 Then
            If e.Item.Checked Then
                CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, p, VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal)
            Else
                CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, p, VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal)
            End If
        End If
    Else
        e.DrawDefault = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Add these Flags: `TextFormatFlags.Left Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping` to TextRenderer. Then, you have to draw the glyph yourself (`CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox()`, considering the state of `e.Item.Checked`). Also, the new bounds only apply to the first SubItem, the others use normal bounds. -- You need to declare the SolidBrush with a `Using` statement: the ListView calls its drawing procedure constantly, you're leaking graphic resources.

Comment: The glyph has an offset. Based on: `Dim glyphSize = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(e.Graphics, VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal)`, the drawing position is `Dim p = New Point(e.Bounds.Location.X + 4, e.Bounds.Y + CInt((e.Bounds.Height - glyphSize.Height) / 2))`

Comment: Thanks for the solution Jimi.  I decided that adding a first column just for the checkboxes was the best solution for various reasons, so have not used the flags that you suggested.  However, I have used your other suggestions including the glyphsize calculation which is less clunky than my own code (recently decided to finally move from VB6 to VB.Net so I'm still getting my head around the .net environment).  I've added the completed code to my original question for those interested.

Answer (score 0):

That code will render the text under the CheckBoxes, the `NewBounds` Rectangle is never actually offset, so you'll also draw the new selection under it.

This is wrong: `New Font(Me.Font, Nothing)`. You need to use the ListView Control's Font, not the Form's. If you want to use a new Font, you need to declare the Font object with a `Using` statement, otherwise you're leaking Graphics resource. Give that that the ListView draws its items very often, it's not good.

Same for the Brush, that's not the way to declare a disposable object with a Using statement. See the code posted here.

It's important that you define the `TextFormatFlags` to use when drawing in a Control that already uses this format, so you won't notice the difference.
It's also important to provide a Rectangle that defines the bounds of the Text, not a Point. Use a Point when you don't care where the Text is drawn. Usually, the Top/Left position.

The hard-coded offsets: **`glyphSize.Width + 7`**, **`e.Bounds.Location.X + 4`** are just default values.

```
Private drawingFlags As TextFormatFlags = TextFormatFlags.Left Or 
        TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping

Private Sub lsvFileList1_DrawSubItem(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs) Handles lsvFileList1.DrawSubItem
    Dim itemBounds As Rectangle
    If e.Item.Selected Then
        If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
            itemBounds = New Rectangle(e.Bounds.Location, e.Bounds.Size)
            Dim glyphSize = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(e.Graphics, VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal)
            itemBounds.X = e.Bounds.X + glyphSize.Width + 7
            Dim p = New Point(e.Bounds.Location.X + 4, e.Bounds.Y + CInt((e.Bounds.Height - glyphSize.Height) / 2))
            CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, p, If(e.Item.Checked, VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal, VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal))
        Else
            itemBounds = e.Bounds
        End If
        Using brush As New SolidBrush(Color.Purple)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, itemBounds)
        End Using
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Text, e.Item.Font, itemBounds, Color.AntiqueWhite, drawingFlags)
    Else
        e.DrawDefault = True
        e.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Bounds)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lsvFileList1_DrawColumnHeader(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs) Handles lsvFileList1.DrawColumnHeader
    e.DrawDefault = True
End Sub
```